# Move Mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial

I have created and used a Mercurial repository in `someFolder`. Now I have discovered the need to keep track of files one level up. So what I would need is to create `someOtherFolder` and move `someFolder` into it. This should be no problem.

At this point I will have

```
someOtherFolder
    someFolder
        .hg
        many other files
```

Is there a way to tell Mercurial to broaden its scope and start keeping track of files inside `someOtherFolder` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's probably a nicer way to do this, but one thing you could do is `hg mv` all the files to a new subdirectory `someFolder` and then rename the parent `someFolder` to `someOtherFolder`, e.g.:

```
someFolder$ mkdir someFolder

someFolder$ hg locate | xargs --replace=FILE hg mv FILE someFolder/FILE

someFolder$ hg status
A someFolder/a.txt
A someFolder/foo/b.txt
R a.txt
R foo/b.txt

someFolder$ hg commit -m "moved files to subfolder"
someFolder$ cd ..
$ mv someFolder someOtherFolder
```

Comment: +1 fantastic. I had to use `-I FILE` instead of `--replace FILE`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [hg convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_to_Mercurial) to do this.

I didn't test this, but something like this may work :

```
$ echo include someFolder > /tmp/myfilemap
$ echo rename someFolder someOtherFolder/someFolder >> /tmp/myfilemap
$ hg convert --filemap /tmp/myfilemap /path/to/repo/foo /tmp/mysubfoo-repo
```